# How can I deal with a file being split into several parts, when I send it to a server?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to write code in Objective C which should send a JPEG file to a server. The problem is that the file is split into several parts, and only the first part is getting there. Is there a way of dealing with this?

Here is some of the code:

```
int j;
for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {        
    // Read in data from appropriate signature file
    NSMutableString *imagePath = [folder_path_2 mutableCopy];
    [imagePath appendString:fn[j]];
    [imagePath appendString:@".jpeg"];
    NSLog(imagePath);

    NSData *imageData = nil;
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath];
    if (fileExists) {
        imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"JPEG image file does not exist.");
    }

    request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    int len = (int)[imageData length];
    length_str  = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", len];
    [request setValue:length_str forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    postBody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

    [request setHTTPBody:postBody];

    // Make connection to the Internet
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil
                                                       error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = (NSString*)[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData
                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(returnString);
}
```

Comment: That truly is 'some' of the code...

Comment: I have now pasted in the rest of the code. I hope it is readable. Is there a way of dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How big is the jpeg file that you're trying to send?